# Trouble addressing sql injection with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection

tl;dr: Rewrote database class using mysql to use PDO instead to make use of prepared statements, but running sqlmap from Kali still extracts tables from the website's database. How?

Longer version:

It came to my attention that one of our websites at work has a SQL injection vulnerability. So I got to looking into it, ran sqlmap from Kali, and it proceeded to extract all the tables from that website's database. Looking into it, the website was using the old mysql api, and after some research I decided switching to PDO to make use of prepared statements would be the answer to fix this vulnerability. So I've mostly rewritten our database class and calls to it to use PDO.

Last night I tested again using sqlmap, and it proceeded to extract all the tables from that website's database.  I was extremely perplexed, and the only thing I could think of is maybe it's using emulated prepared statements instead of native prepared statements, so I added the option upon creation of the PDO handle to disable emulation.  But apparently that didn't make any difference, either.

The Question:

What am I missing? How is there still a sql injection vulnerability that sqlmap is exploiting? How do I effectively address this?

Code:

Here is the calling code:

```
public function Load($DbObject, $userName, $password) {
    /* @var $DbObject DB */
    if ($userName == "" || $password == "") {
        $this->errMessage = "You must complete all fields.";
        return (FALSE);
    }
    $fields = array("generic", "db", "fields");
    $where_fields = array("userName", "password");
    $where_values = array($userName, $password);
    if ($DbObject->SelectQuery("db_table", $fields, $where_fields, $where_values)) {
        if ($DbObject->RecordCount() == 1) {
            $ret_val = TRUE;
            $results = $DbObject->FetchResult();
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($fields); $i++) {
                $this->{"$fields[$i]"} = $results[0][$i];
            }
        } else {
            $this->errMessage = "<error_message>";
            $ret_val = FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        $this->errMessage = "<another_error_message>";
        $ret_val = FALSE;
    }
    return ($ret_val);
}
```

Here's the relevant code from the database class:

```
function SelectQuery($db_table, $db_fields, $where_fields = NULL, $where_values = NULL) {
    $ret_val = TRUE;
    $query = "SELECT " . implode(", ", $db_fields) . " FROM " . $db_table;

    $numFields = count($where_fields);

    if ($numFields > 0) {
        $query .= " WHERE ";
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($where_fields as $field) {
            $query .= "$field = ?";
            if ($i < $numFields) {
                $query .= " AND ";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }

    try {
        $stmt = $this->db_handle->prepare($query);
        if (is_null($where_fields)) {
            $stmt->execute();
        } else {
            $stmt->execute($where_values);
        }
        $this->db_result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $this->db_numRecords = count($this->db_result);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $ret_val = FALSE;
        $this->db_errNumber = '<err_msg>' . $stmt->errorCode();
        $this->db_errMessage = '<second_err_msg>' . $stmt->errorInfo();
        $this->db_errDetailMessage = '<third_err_msg>' . $query;
    }
    return $ret_val;
}

function DB($type, $user, $pass, $host, $name) {
    // set the default values for the DataBase class
    $this->db_type = $type;
    $this->db_user = $user;
    $this->db_password = $pass;
    $this->db_host = $host;
    $this->db_name = $name;
    $this->db_dsn = $type . ":host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $name;
}

function OpenConnection() {
    $returnValue = TRUE;
    try {
        $this->db_handle = new PDO($this->db_dsn, $this->db_user, $this->db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE));
        $this->db_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $returnValue = FALSE;
        $this->db_errNumber = 002; /* ??? */
        $this->db_errMessage = "<error_message>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return ($returnValue);
}
```

And here's the sql statement it is generating when a user logs in:

```
SELECT generic, db, fields FROM db_table WHERE userName = ? AND password = ?
```

According to sqlmap, here's the payload it's using: (redacted)

Any guidance or advice you could provide on making this code more robust against SQL injection vulnerabilities would be very much appreciated!!

EDIT - Here is some additional information about my setup that may or may not be relevant:
We're using PHP 5.4.16 and MariaDB 5.5.40.  From phpinfo() it appears the pdo_mysql driver we are using is actually supplied by MariaDB rather than using mysqlnd. This seems appropriate since we're using MariaDB instead of MySQL. Could this at all affect using native prepared statements?
[image: PDO section of phpinfo() output]

Comment: Is prepared statement emulation turned off?

Comment: Make sure your PDO connection looks something similar to this: `$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Does sqlmap has cache of some sort? Has it been cleared? I don't see anything suspicious in your code, or maybe I missed it.

Comment: Double check that 1) you are really using new code, and 2) sqlmap is connecting to new webserver and not to old webserver.

Comment: imo, I would: debugging: `var_dump($query, __FILE__.__LINE__);`  immediately before the prepare statement. You will see the query with placeholders. Further debugging is to use 'general logging' in the database to see what it is actually getting / doing. Do that later if required.

Comment: @RobertRocha: Unless I'm mistaken, these two lines disable emulation and set the error mode like you're saying. The only difference I see is I am not stipulating the charset. `$this->db_handle = new PDO($this->db_dsn, $this->db_user, $this->db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE));
        $this->db_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @frz3993 Thank you for reviewing my code! Glad nothing stands out as being suspicious. I am not aware of any cache that may be persisting with sqlmap, but I admit I am not confident in this. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @MarkusLaire 1) The new code is definitely what's running. I have tons of debug statements in the new code that are being executed. 2) Same webserver, just new code running on it.

Comment: @RyanVincent Great ideas! I actually have a lot of debugging statements in my code that I removed before posting. They're similar to `error_log("<filename>: <method> <property>" . var_export($property,true),1, <emailaddress>);`. From this I was able to see the prepared statement with the placeholders (see the last code box in my post). I can also see the contents of the 'where arrays'. Also, I requested IT enable general logging in phpMyAdmin, but it never gives me any data. It only reports "Log analysed, but no data found in this time span."

Comment: I edited the original post with some additional information about our specific setup. I'm not sure if it's relevant to this issue or not. It seems to be recommended to use mysqlnd, but we're actually using MariaDB instead of MySQL, so it appears that we're using a MariaDB driver for PDO as well?

Comment: @goodmike - mysqlnd means MySQL native driver. It's used to represent MySQL's data types such as integers correctly in PHP. When it's not present, PHP treats everything you select and retrieve as a string. Basically, it's not the same thing as MariaDB because MariaDB is a MySQL fork, while mysqlnd is a piece of code acting as a driver. TL;DR: it's not the source of your problem.